# Refreshing information in AngularJS when URL changes (without refresh)

Tags: angularjs

In AngularJS I have a service with a method used to return a single post from the API. It is set up as such...

```
.factory('Posts', ['$resource', '$routeParams',

    function($resource, $routeParams){

        return $resource('/api/posts/', {}, {
                single: {
                    url: '/api/posts/' + $routeParams.post_id,
                    method:'GET',
                }

    });

}])
```

I have a route provider set up to view single posts at the url: /#/p/14

This works correctly when I first land on the page but if I then change the number on the end nothing happens until I refresh. As the URL has a # in I understand why this is but not how to solve the issue. I can't seem to find anything whilst on the Googles. Hope someone can help!

Comment: how are you changing number? If you mean manually changing in address bar browser doesn't know when you finished typing/editing url until you click on refresh....shouldn't load page from server though if only change hash

Comment: At this point it's purely typing in to the address bar and hitting enter. If I do that it doesn't seem react at all though if I hit refresh after doing that it updates the content. I was expecting AngularJS to notice a change and update the scope but I'm guessing I need to do something else?

Comment: would try playing with demo on angular site, or any other angular app, and see if same problem occurs in browser you are using. Hard to help without being able to replicate...http://angular.github.io/angular-phonecat/step-12/app/#/phones.

Comment: also factory obviously works, post controller and route code

Comment: how did you specify your routes?

Comment: @charlietfl Thanks for your comments, really appreciate it. It managed to put me on the right track to work out where I was going wrong. I've documented what went wrong for my answer!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the help in the comments on the original post. That put me on the right track to diagnose the problem. It was a bit of a rookie error which I'll explain below for anyone who may find the same.

The problem was in how I set up my controller and service to draw the id of the post from the URL. As per the original post you can see that I was calling the URL parameter in the factory using $routeParams.post_id. Adding the variable to the end like this isn't the correct way to do it, it is in fact as per below:

```
.factory('Posts', ['$resource', '$routeParams',
    function($resource){
        return $resource('/api/posts/', {}, {
                single: {
                    url: '/api/posts/:post_id',
                    method:'GET',
                }
    });
}])
```

I had tried this originally but it didn't seem to work, revisiting the problem and looking through the example code link provided in the comments I realised I'd mistaken the purpose of the parameters in my call to it from the controller.

Problematic:

```
Posts.single({}, function(response){ 
   $scope.post = response ; 
});
```

Working:

```
Posts.single({ post_id: $routeParams.post_id }, function(response){ 
   $scope.post = response ; 
});
```

I hadn't realised these parameters would be used to bind that information, I thought they were used purely for the GET information on the factory request.

Once I'd sorted those things out it worked no problems!

**TL; DR**

This is painfully bad way to do use $routeParams in a factory, pass it from the controller.

```
 url: '/api/posts/' + $routeParams.post_id,
```